# Access database shows as read-only on one workstation (unless logging in with domain admin privileges)

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-access, read-only

We have an Access database stored on a central server on our LAN, accessed by 20 domain-joined PCs (15x Windows 7, 5x XP).

For some reason, one of our XP workstations only allows users to access the database in read-only mode:

[image: Read-only error message]

If I log in as the domain administrator (or temporarily give a user domain admin privileges) the error no longer appears when they try to connect to the database.

The database on the server is not directly accessible from the network. We use a third party database client on the workstations, which connects to an instance of SQL Server running on the server.

As far as I can see, all the workstations are configured identically - so I can't see why one PC is only letting domain administrators write to the database.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions for the share, folder and files on the server? Can you copy a text file (or something) to the shared  folder on the server?

Comment: The database on the server is not directly accessible from the network. We use a third party database client on the workstations, which connects to an instance of SQL Server running on the server. As far as I can see, all the workstations are configured identically - so I can't see why one PC is only letting domain administrators write to the database.